# Retrieve top n in each group of a DataFrame in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

There's a DataFrame in pyspark with data as below:

```
user_id object_id score
user_1  object_1  3
user_1  object_1  1
user_1  object_2  2
user_2  object_1  5
user_2  object_2  2
user_2  object_2  6
```

What I expect is returning 2 records in each group with the same user_id, which need to have the highest score. Consequently, the result should look as the following:

```
user_id object_id score
user_1  object_1  3
user_1  object_2  2
user_2  object_2  6
user_2  object_1  5
```

I'm really new to pyspark, could anyone give me a code snippet or portal to the related documentation of this problem? Great thanks!

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I believe you need to use [window functions](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) to attain the rank of each row based on `user_id` and `score`, and subsequently filter your results to only keep the first two values.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank, col

window = Window.partitionBy(df['user_id']).orderBy(df['score'].desc())

df.select('*', rank().over(window).alias('rank')) 
  .filter(col('rank') <= 2) 
  .show() 
#+-------+---------+-----+----+
#|user_id|object_id|score|rank|
#+-------+---------+-----+----+
#| user_1| object_1|    3|   1|
#| user_1| object_2|    2|   2|
#| user_2| object_2|    6|   1|
#| user_2| object_1|    5|   2|
#+-------+---------+-----+----+
```

In general, the official [programming guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html) is a good place to start learning Spark.

#### Data

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([("user_1",  "object_1",  3), 
                      ("user_1",  "object_2",  2), 
                      ("user_2",  "object_1",  5), 
                      ("user_2",  "object_2",  2), 
                      ("user_2",  "object_2",  6)])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["user_id", "object_id", "score"])
```

Comment: I thinks there's something need to tweak. object_id doesn't have effect on either `groupby` or `top` procedure. And what I want is to `group by` user_id, and in each group, retrieve the first **two** records with highest score separately, not only the first records. Great thanks!

Comment: You can use the window function in the filter: `df.filter(rank().over(window) <= 2) `

Comment: I'm flabbergasted... I was convinced I used a window function in a filter before. But I indeed couldn't reproduce it (neither in 2 nor in 1.6). I did use it in an exotic way, but I can't remember when or how. Sorry.

Comment: You might want to consider using `row_number` instead of `rank` in case of getting same rank and you still want top n

Comment: @TomerBenDavid this comment deserves more upvote, thank you sir.

Answer (score 39):

Top-n is more accurate if using `row_number` instead of `rank` when getting rank equality:

```
val n = 5
df.select(col('*'), row_number().over(window).alias('row_number')) \
  .where(col('row_number') <= n) \
  .limit(20) \
  .toPandas()
```

> Note `limit(20).toPandas()` trick instead of `show()` for Jupyter notebooks for nicer formatting.

Comment: Remember to add `from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number` for this to work

Comment: What would be more efficient (fast) to compute?. I suspect that is about the same.

Would it be a more efficient way? I am dealing with a 110 GB dataset with 4.7 M categories (to groupBy), with around 4,300 rows each category and its taking for ever on a large cluster.

Comment: Here's the best link to describe the [difference between rank, row_number, and dense_rank](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/difference-between-rownumber-rank-denserank-in-sql-server#:~:text=Row_Number%20%28%29%20will%20generate%20a%20unique%20number%20for,the%20same%20value%20without%20skipping%20the%20next%20number.)

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is asked for `pyspark` and I was looking for the similar answer in `Scala` i.e.

> Retrieve top n values in each group of a DataFrame in Scala

Here is the `scala` version of @mtoto's answer.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rank
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val window = Window.partitionBy("user_id").orderBy('score desc')
val rankByScore = rank().over(window)
df1.select('*, rankByScore as 'rank).filter(col("rank") <= 2).show() 
# you can change the value 2 to any number you want. Here 2 represents the top 2 values
```

More examples can be found [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-functions-windows.html).

Answer (score 1):

with Python 3 and Spark 2.4

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

def get_topN(df, group_by_columns, order_by_column, n=1):
    window_group_by_columns = Window.partitionBy(group_by_columns)
    ordered_df = df.select(df.columns + [
        f.row_number().over(window_group_by_columns.orderBy(order_by_column.desc())).alias('row_rank')])
    topN_df = ordered_df.filter(f"row_rank <= {n}").drop("row_rank")
    return topN_df

top_n_df = get_topN(your_dataframe, [group_by_columns],[order_by_columns], 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution without a window function to get the top N records from pySpark DataFrame.

```
# Import Libraries
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# Sample Data
rdd = sc.parallelize([("user_1",  "object_1",  3), 
                      ("user_1",  "object_2",  2), 
                      ("user_2",  "object_1",  5), 
                      ("user_2",  "object_2",  2), 
                      ("user_2",  "object_2",  6)])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["user_id", "object_id", "score"])

# Get top n records as Row Objects
row_list = df.orderBy(col("score").desc()).head(5)

# Convert row objects to DF
sorted_df = spark.createDataFrame(row_list)

# Display DataFrame
sorted_df.show()
```

Output

```
+-------+---------+-----+
|user_id|object_id|score|
+-------+---------+-----+
| user_1| object_2|    2|
| user_2| object_2|    2|
| user_1| object_1|    3|
| user_2| object_1|    5|
| user_2| object_2|    6|
+-------+---------+-----+
```

If you are interested in more window functions in Spark you can refer to one of my blogs: https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/deep-dive-into-apache-spark-window-functions-7b4e39ad3c86

Comment: Is this one doing less computation than the order by necessary in window?

Answer (score 0):

To Find Nth highest value in PYSPARK SQLquery using `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT e.*, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col_name DESC) rn 
    FROM Employee e
)
WHERE rn = N
```

N is the nth highest value required from the column

Output:

```
[Stage 2:>               (0 + 1) / 1]++++++++++++++++
+-----------+
|col_name   |
+-----------+
|1183395    |
+-----------+
```

query will return N highest value