# Hive - Remove duplicates, keeping newest record - all of it

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce, hive

There have been a few questions like this, with no answer, like this one [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36089783/remove-duplicates-using-map-reduce-or-hive)

I thought I would post another in hopes of getting one.

I have a hive table with duplicate rows.  Consider the following example:

```
*ID             Date           value1         value2*
1001            20160101       alpha          beta
1001            20160201       delta          gamma
1001            20160115       rho            omega
1002            20160101       able           charlie
1002            20160101       able           charlie
```

When complete, I only want two records.  Specifically, these two:

```
*ID             Date           value1         value2*
1001            20160201       delta          gamma
1002            20160101       able           charlie
```

Why those two?  For the ID=1001, I want the latest date and the data that is in that row with it.  For the ID=1002, really the same answer, but the two records with that ID are complete duplicates, and I only want one.

So, any suggestions on how to do this?  The simple "group by" using the ID and the 'max' date won't work, as that ignores the other columns.  I cannot put 'max' on those, as it will pull the max columns from all the records (will pull 'rho' from an older record), which is not good.

I hope my explanation is clear, and I appreciate any insight.

Thank you

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38398563/4964651) help?

Comment: Thank mtoto.  Works great!!!  I guess I am going to have to get into Windowing.  Post as a "answer" and you get a check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH temp_cte AS (
        SELECT      mt.ID                                                           AS ID 
                    , mt.Date                                                       AS Date 
                    , mt.value1                                                     AS value1 
                    , mt.value2                                                     AS value2
                    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mt.ID ORDER BY mt.Date DESC)  AS row_num
        FROM        my_table mt
    )
    SELECT      tc.ID           AS ID 
                , tc.Date       AS Date 
                , tc.value1     AS value1
                , tc.value2     AS value2
    FROM        temp_cte tc 
    WHERE       tc.row_num = 1 
    ;
```

Or you can do MAX() and join the table to itself where ID = ID and max_date = Date.  HTH.

Edit March 2022:
Since ROW_NUMBER numbers every row and the user only cares about 1 row with the max date there's a better way to do this I discovered.

```
WITH temp_cte AS (
    SELECT      mt.ID                                                                               AS ID 
                , MAX(NAMED_STRUCT('Date', mt.Date, 'Value1', mt.value1, 'Value2', mt.Value2))      AS my_struct
    FROM        my_table mt
    GROUP BY    mt.ID 
)
SELECT      tt.ID                       AS ID 
            , tt.my_struct.Date         AS Date
            , tt.my_struct.Value1       AS Value1
            , tt.my_struct.Value2       AS Value2
FROM        temp_cte tt 
;
```

Comment: this soln would not work if the sequence of ids are not consecutive in the input table.

Comment: I'm not understanding. They wanted the max date for each ID and the ROW_NUMBER() partitions by ID. It will work for any ID set.  However, since answering this question I found a better way to do this in Hive using NAMED_STRUCT()

Comment: WITH temp_cte AS (
    SELECT      mt.ID                                                                               AS ID 
                , MAX(NAMED_STRUCT('Date', mt.Date, 'Value1', mt.value1, 'Value2', mt.Value2))      AS my_struct
    FROM        my_table mt
    GROUP BY    mt.ID 
)
SELECT      tt.ID                       AS ID 
            , tt.my_struct.Date         AS Date
            , tt.my_struct.Value1       AS Value1
            , tt.my_struct.Value2       AS Value2
FROM        temp_cte tt 
;

Comment: The only time it might not work is if ID is NULL.  I'll let someone else test that though.