# Spark, Scala - How to get Top 3 value from each group of two column in dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have one DataFrame which contains these values :

```
Dept_id  |  name  | salary
 1           A       10
 2           B       100
 1           D       100
 2           C       105
 1           N       103
 2           F       102
 1           K       90
 2           E       110
```

I want the result in this form :

```
Dept_id  |  name  | salary
 1           N       103
 1           D       100
 1           K       90
 2           E       110
 2           C       105 
 2           F       102
```

Thanks In Advance :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the solution is similar to [Retrieve top n in each group of a DataFrame in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397796/retrieve-top-n-in-each-group-of-a-dataframe-in-pyspark) which is in pyspark

If you do the same in scala, then it should be as below

```
df.withColumn("rank", rank().over(Window.partitionBy("Dept_id").orderBy($"salary".desc)))
    .filter($"rank" <= 3)
    .drop("rank")
```

I hope the answer is helpful