# Aggregate as a sum of 3 largest values in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe grouped by 'id' and 'type':

```
+---+----+-----+
| id|type|count|
+---+----+-----+
|  0|   A|    2|
|  0|   B|    3|
|  0|   C|    1|
|  0|   D|    3|
|  0|   G|    1|
|  1|   A|    0|
|  1|   C|    1|
|  1|   D|    1|
|  1|   G|    2|
+---+----+-----+
```

I would like now to group by 'id' and get a sum of 3 largest values:

```
+---+-----+
| id|count|
+---+-----+
|  0|    8|
|  1|    4|
+---+-----+
```

How can I do it in pyspark, so that the computation is relatively efficient?

**Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397796/retrieve-top-n-in-each-group-of-a-dataframe-in-pyspark)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to perform this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
df = spark.createDataFrame([
(0, "A", 2),
(0,"B", 3),
(0,"C", 1),
(0,"D", 3),
(1,"A", 0),
(1,"C", 1),
(1,"D", 1),
(1,"G", 2)
], ("id", "type", "count"))

my_window = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("count")
df.withColumn("last_3", lead("count").over(my_window)).groupBy("id").agg(sum("last_3")).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----------+
| id|sum(last_3)|
+---+-----------+
|  0|          8|
|  1|          4|
+---+-----------+
```

Details:  Window partitions your data by `id` and orders it by `count` then you create a new column where `lead` uses this window and returns the next value in that group (which was created by the window) so `(0,C,1)` is the lowest tuple in the group for `id=0` this receive the value `2` since it is the next highest in this group (from tuple `(0,A,2)` and so on. The highest tuple does not have a following value and is assigned `null`. Finally perform the group operation and the sum.

Comment: The fact is that there can be any number of rows with the same id (not just 4).